# Differences between Session Fixation and Session Identifier not Updated

Tags: php, session

I am working on a web site and my job is to secure the site from all types of vulnerabilities like XSS and so on.

I ran AppScan, a IBM tool to check for vulnerabilities after my code changes and I see an error saying "Session Identifier Not Updated" in the report and saying

Threat Classification:
Session Fixation

I am generating new cookies for each request and that's how we resolved Session Fixation issue I believe. Is that correct?

One important question I want to ask is - What is the difference between "Session Fixation" and "Session Identifier Not Updated"

Comment: Doesn't documentation for the product you use explain all the terms it works with?

Comment: @zerkms, I posted this question after searching everything in the Appscan help docs but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: you're kindding right? I've put "AppScan Session Fixation" to the google and it provided a link to the pdf with a thorough explanation in the first link.

Comment: I know the definition for "SESSION FIXATION" and "SESSION IDENTIFIERS NOT UPDATED" from the report. What I want to know is the difference between them. Please don't think that I am kidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you changing the session id every time the session changes state? This is most likely your problem.

If your site accepts a session id as a URL parameter and you do not change it when someone logs in, this can be the problem. For example:

1) I send you the link www.example.com/?sess_id=123456

2) You visit the link to the site and login. Session id 123456 is now your session.

3) I visit www.example.com/?sess_id=123456 and I'm now logged in as you.

When the user logs in at step 2, you need to *re-generate* a new session id, because the session changed state. Even if the session id is server generated, and will only accept a server generated id, I can still fixate your session.

1) I visit www.example.com and see that the session id 654321 is returned.

2) I send you the link www.example.com/?sess_id=654321 and you login.

3) I visit www.example.com/?sess_id=654321 and I'm now logged in as you.

Without more info this may not be the cause of your problem but it's most likely from what you've provided. Check that when the session changes state, the session id is re-generated (when the user logs in/out).

Comment: =============================REQUEST HEADERS BEFORE LOGIN========================

Cookie: some cookie value

=============================POST REQUEST RESPONSE HEADERS AFTER LOGIN=====================
Set-Cookie: 
cookie 1:............
cookie 2: ...............

So the cookie values are different for request(before login) and response (after login). Does that mean the issue is resolved ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure I understand what it is you're trying to say.

Comment: If the cookie values are different before login and after login then does that mean the "Session Fixation" is resolved? Also if possible can you please explain difference between "SESSION FIXATION" and "SESSION IDENTIFIERS NOT UPDATED"? w.r.t Appscan?

Comment: Yes, as long as the session id is changed, usually with a call to `session_regenerate_id()`, then it should be fixed. Though, if that's the case, you have to wonder why AppScan flagged it?

Comment: Please explain difference between "SESSION FIXATION" and "SESSION IDENTIFIERS NOT UPDATED". I am surprised to see we are not calling session_regenerate_id() function on successfull authentication. I need to debug the code once again. I will post one more comment in few minutes. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Session fixation is caused by the session identifiers not being updated. That's what allows an attacker to fixate the session.

Answer (score -1):

`$_SESSION` super global with corresponding session ids. For example,

```
 $_SESSION[“member_id”], $_SESSION[“display_name”].
```